# angular $http promise being returned twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to evaluate an expression in an if statement to return `true` or `false`. The function's evaluation depends on `$http` promises, of which the documentation out there is plentiful—so I'm confident I can get this figured out.

However, I noticed something odd in my console, and that is that it seems the `.success` callback is being ran twice, as the console is outputting the output from the success callback twice (i.e. `the call was a success` is being logged twice)!

From looking at the code, my understanding would be that the `save()` causes `securityCheck.checkLogin()` to log `undefined`, the if statement to evaluate to false (thereby logging `function returned false`),  and then the promise to return with `the call was a success` to be logged once. Why is it being logged twice?

script

```
angular.module('login', ['security'])
.directive('loginDirective', ['$parse', 'securityCheck', function($parse, securityCheck) {
    return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, form) {
      scope.save = function() {
        console.log(securityCheck.checkLogin());
           //evaluates to undefined, promise not returned yet
        if (securityCheck.checkLogin()) {
          console.log("function returned true");
        } else {
          console.log("function returned false");
        }
      }
    }
    };
}]);

angular.module('security', [])
.factory('securityCheck', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var security = {
    checkLogin: function() {
        $http.get('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/lagrossetete/collections/avengers?apiKey=j0PIJH2HbfakfRo1ELKkX0ShST6_F78A')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('the call was a success!');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('the call had an error.');
            });
    }
    };
    return security;
}]);
```

html

```
<html ng-app="login">
  <body>
    <login-directive ng-click="save()">click me</login-directive>
  </body>
</html>
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tM7eHniDRvCLhzAw7Kzo?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well remove `console.log(securityCheck.checkLogin());` and request will be issued only once. However this is only minor problem with your code. Real one is that you treat AJAX request as if it was synchronous, however it's not. `checkLogin` method doesn't return `true/false` it returns promise object, and asynchronously.

You should check for auth result inside of `then` callback:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, form) {
  scope.save = function() {
      securityCheck.checkLogin().then(function(check) {
        if (check) {
          console.log("function returned true");
        } else {
          console.log("function returned false");
        }
      });
  }
}
```

You also need to make factory method return promise:

```
angular.module('security', [])
.factory('securityCheck', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var security = {
    checkLogin: function() {
        return $http.get('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/lagrossetete/collections/avengers?apiKey=j0PIJH2HbfakfRo1ELKkX0ShST6_F78A')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('the call was a success!');
                return data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('the call had an error.');
            });
    }
    };
    return security;
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Kj8PkLMv3PsLfe9fsaRo?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You do realize, you are calling `checkLogin()` method twice:

```
 console.log(securityCheck.checkLogin());
    //evaluates to undefined, promise not returned yet
 if (securityCheck.checkLogin()) {
```

This causes `$http.get()` to be executed twice, and so is your `success` implementation.

Comment: Embarrassing. I didn't know logging it to the console would cause it to execute. Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: You're logging the result of executing the method `checkLogin()` and the method does not return anything (no return statement in it), this it logs `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You call the console.log once in your directive and then once again in your factory function.

```
// Here in the directive
scope.save = function() {    
    console.log(securityCheck.checkLogin());

// And then here in the service
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('the call was a success!');
```

Although different commands, they both return the same value